# Creating a table to query in Spark using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load a file directly from S3 and ultimately trying to just do some SparkSQL on it. Eventually, I plan on bringing in multiple files which will be multiple tables (1:1 map between files and tables).

So I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/python-spark-sql-dataframes) that is fairly good at describing each step. I'm a bit stuck on declaring the proper schema and which variable, if any, is referred in the `FROM` clause in the SQL statement.

Here's my code:

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS region (region_id INT, name STRING, comment STRING)")
region = sc.textFile("s3n://thisisnotabucketname/region.tbl")

raw_data = sc.textFile("s3n://thisisnotabucketname/region.tbl")
csv_data = raw_data.map(lambda l: l.split("|"))
row_data = csv_data.map(lambda p: Row( region_id=int(p[0]), name=p[1], comment=p[2] ))

interactions_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_data)
interactions_df.registerTempTable("interactions")

tcp_interactions = sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT region_id, name, comment FROM region WHERE region_id > 1 """)
tcp_interactions = sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT * FROM region """)
tcp_interactions.show()
```

And here's some sample data. **There is no header**

```
0|AFRICA|lar deposits. blithely final packages cajole. regular waters are final requests. regular accounts are according to |
1|AMERICA|hs use ironic, even requests. s|
2|ASIA|ges. thinly even pinto beans ca|
```

`tcp_interactions.show()` is returning nothing. Just the header of `region_id|name|comment|`. What am I doing incorrectly? In the SQL statement, is `region` pointing to the `region` variable declared in the first line of code, or is it pointing to something else?

Comment: are you intentionally registering a table named `interactions` and then selecting from a table named `region`, or is this just a mistake in copy-pasting into SO? If not - that's your issue right there...

Comment: Ah yeah, looks like I made a table using this command earlier in that SSH session: `sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS region (region_id INT, name STRING, comment STRING)")`. What would be the function for loading that table from the file `s3n://thisisnotabucketname/region.tbl`?

Comment: Okay, now I see what you were talking about. I changed `interactions` to `region` and that worked. Is this a recommended way of importing data? I know it's highly recommended to convert files into parquet format for ingestion, but is the method I used typically inefficient?